# Using vssadmin through a batch command or powershell

Tags: windows, batch-file, volume-shadow-service

I need to access a file that is open by another process all the time. The best way would be for me to use Windows Shadow Copy to create another copy of the file and then use the copied file.

Does anyone know how to use vssadmin to create a backup and extract a specific file through a batch command or power shell? I would like to automate the process to run every night.

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page with examples on how to create snapshots from a command line with vssadmin:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/12/14/301868.aspx

Comment: Actually using mklink /d as described in this page worked for me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2008/02/28/a-simple-way-to-access-shadow-copies-in-vista.aspx